# Failed to decrypt data key x.pem to decrypt messages unable to process block at Consumer in apache pulsar with version v2.0.0-rc1-incubating

Tags: java, encryption, consumer, apache-pulsar

Producer publishes same messages to a topic encrypted with different public keys to consume by different applications with a set of public key and private key.

Apllication Consumer able to consume the corresponding message and tries to consume the other application message as well and getting the exception as below.

SEVERE: [topicname] [subscriptionname] Failed to decrypt data key xx.pem to decrypt messages unable to process block
Sep 04, 2022 9:57:40 AM org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.MessageCrypto decryptDataKey

Used ConsumerCryptoFailureAction.DISCARD  during the consumer creation and it is not helpful.

Any idea  how to skip the other application targetted messages?

Sample code used:

```
                    try {
                        org.apache.pulsar.client.api.Consumer consumer = pulsarClient.newConsumer().consumerName(consumerName).topic(topicname)
                                .subscriptionName(subscriptionname).subscriptionType("Shared")
                                .cryptoKeyReader(new RawFileKeyReader(publickey , privatekey))
                                .cryptoFailureAction(ConsumerCryptoFailureAction.DISCARD)
                                .subscribe();
                    } catch (CryptoException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


            try {
                consumerRecord = consumer.receive(3, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            } catch (CryptoException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Can you please provvide more details. Do you get any messages back from the apache. You may provvide the code snippet that doesn't work